# Custom hook to attach event listener to an HTML element (div) stored as ref using useRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a custom hook named **useSwipe**, which must **add event handlers** for `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` to an HTML element, which I'm storing as a **ref** by using the `useRef()` hook. And should **also execute a callback** when those events are fired.

**My Component**

```
function Component() {
  const divRef = useRef(null);  // The ref for the element

  useSwipe(divRef.current,someFunction);

  function someFunction() {
    console.log('Something happened...');
  }

  return (
    <div ref={divRef}>
      Some Content
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Custom Hook: useSwipe.js**

```
import {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

function useSwipe(element, callback) {

useEffect(() => {

  function onTouchStart() {
    callback();
  }
  function onTouchMove() {
    callback();
  }
  function onTouchEnd() {
    callback();
  }

  if (element !== null) {
      element.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart);
      element.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);
      element.addEventListener('touchend', onTouchEnd);
  }

  return () => {
      if (element !== null) {
        console.log('useSwipe useEffect return...');
        element.removeEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart);
        element.removeEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);
        element.removeEventListener('touchend', onTouchEnd);
      }
  };

});

}

export default useSwipe;
```

**QUESTION**

Is it a bad practice to add and remove event listeners on every render? Does it hurt performance?

I could add `element` and `callback` in a dependency array for the `useEffect()` as seen below, but since callback will change on every render (in my case) the result would be the same. I'll be adding and removing the listeners on every render.

`useEffect(()=>{},[element,callback]);`

Is there a way for me to add those event listeners only one time at mount, and remove them at dismount? I couldn't think of a way, because every time I try to do that, I get stale versions of the handlers (they need to be updated because of the new `callbacks` that they receive. So I ended up recreating everything: handlers and listeners.

Comment: Is the callback changing on every render simply because it's defined in the component? If so, there's a [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook that helps with that.

Comment: I tried that, but in my real scenario I'd have to update that `useCallback` along with a state that that callback changes, so I end up recreating basically on every render again. But thanks!